# Handling external code exceptions in python

Tags: python, exception, code-organization

I have:

1. a function `call_vendor_code()` that calls external vendor code;
2. an exception class `MyDomainException(Exceprion)`.

I know that function `call_vendor_code()` could throw `MyDomainException` (because that logic in function is my). But how do I know which vendor code exceptions could be thrown in `call_vendor_code()` in subcalls?

Example:

```
def call_vendor_code():
    if not vendor.package.module.make_more_love():
        raise MyDomainException('Not enough love.')
```

Vendor code could throw any other exceptions that I don't handle. It is possible to intercept all excepions from vendor code, but i thing that it is bad solution.

```
def call_vendor_code():
    try:
        if not vendor.package.module.make_more_love():
            raise MyDomainException('Not enough love.')
    except Exception, e:
        raise MyDomainException(e)
```

How to interact/not interact with other-level exceptions?

Comment: Why is that a bad thing? To ensure all exceptions are wrapped, something needs to be done.

Comment: @simeon-visser for example, we lose a backtrace.

Comment: yes, but that's a Python issue, not an application logic issue. Wrapping exceptions is still okay. Python 3 has made improvements in this area: http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/08/03/the-most-underrated-feature-in-python-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is sound.

How you handle these vendor specific exceptions, more elegantly, depends
on the type of exceptions raised by the vendor code.

Are they plain python exceptions(e.g. ValueError, TypeError, etc)? Then
you don't have much of a choice. You should wrap them under a generic
`except Exception` statement. In these unfortunate cases, many people
try to differentiate the type of error by parsing the exception message.
A major anti-pattern, but what can you do?

Do they raise their own vendor specific exceptions(best case scenario)?
Then you can easily differentiate and handle them more elegantly in your
code. They *should* have some kind of documentation about it :)
Or, if the code is available, read through the code and see for yourself.

If we're talking about vendor code that talks to some external system(some
kind of DB for example), they might have a generic VendorException with
some internal error code(1133, 623, whatever) that is stored in the exception
instance as an attribute. Again, they most probably will have a listing of
those error codes, along with their description in some kind of documentation,
that you can use to map them into your own custom exceptions.